# Reading values from local.settings.json using powershell azure function apps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to read a value from my local.settings.json file using powershell function app but it doesnt seem to be reading the value

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "powershell",
      "NSGNAME":"dev-apps-ext-ase1-NSG"
      
    }
    
  }
```

Retrieving in FA using

```
Write-Host $env:NSGNAME

write-host $env:FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME
```

Bottom one works top one does not return anything?  any help please

Comment: Is `ConvertFrom-Json` being used?

Comment: no nothing like that just what is above

Comment: Are there any other values as well after `"NSGNAME": "dev-apps-ext-ase1-NSG",` ? If not, remove that comma at the end of `"NSGNAME": "dev-apps-ext-ase1-NSG"`. Could be a syntactical issue.

Comment: so that was a typo - it wasnt there originally

Comment: Ensure that you've published these values to Azure, because these settings are not migrated automatically when the project is published

Answer (score 0):

I created the local.settings.json inside my FA folder where the run.ps1 is located.  VScode already had created the file on the higher level folder - modifying this worked